# Hi, I wanted to understand and Identify the error and fix the code in the following Visual Basic Code

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(...) Handles btnDisplay.Click    
    Dim major As String    
    major = "Computer Science"  
    If major = "Business" Or "Computer Science" Then      
    txtOutput.Text = "Yes"   
    End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: `If major = "Business" Or major = "Computer Science" Then...`  Do try to write better titles in the future

Comment: In addition to what @Plutonix has said, you should also include the error message. We don't like guessing what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` **operator**

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(...) Handles btnDisplay.Click    
    Dim major As String    
    major = "Computer Science"  
    If major = "Business" Or major = "Computer Science" Then      
    txtOutput.Text = "Yes"   
    End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: **not** a valid VB operator